# Show Attribute Label

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I am trying to display the label for my attribute (i.e. 'color:'). I have added the following code to my 'media.phtml' file:

```
<div class="color-option">
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("color"); ?>
</div>
```

Which displays the value. But how do I get it to also show the label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getStoreLabel();
```

Copied from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332460/magento-get-custom-attribute-label).